# The authentication endpoint Kerberos was not found on the configured Secure Token Service

Tags: crm, kerberos, adfs

I've encountered a challenge regarding internet-facing deployment installation for CRM using a AD FS server. After the setup is complete, users are able to access the CRM server - but when trying to run custom pages the following error message is prompted:

"The authentication endpoint Kerberos was not found on the configured Secure Token Service!"

I've found several solutions on the internet for this issue:

1. First I found a KB article from Microsoft providing a possible
   solution, this involves updating MEX endpoints by running a provided
   PowerShell script.
   (https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2828015/configuring-ad-fs-2.1-with-microsoft-dynamics-crm-2011).
   But this doesn't seem to be the issue.
2. Another solution could be to update the CRM rollup version (currently have version 14 installed, latest is version 18) - this is something that I want to avoid as it might lead to further issues.

Have anybody else encountered a similar issue, and in that case how did you solve it?

Answer (score 0):

I have just spent last few days to figure this exact same error message and it turned out that it was the "Domain" attribute in crm connection string. Copied my answer to my own question at the Microsoft [Dynamics CRM community forum](https://community.dynamics.com/crm/f/microsoft-dynamics-crm-forum/392407/organizationservice-connect-error-the-authentication-endpoint-kerberos-was-not-found-on-the-configured-secure-token-service-from-developer-viewpoint/1059105#1059105) here:

"Well, I found the culprit - it was the Domain attribute in the connection string:

For connecting from outside the domain, it does not like to have a **Domain** in the connection string:

1. Connection string format 1 (without Domain attribute): "Authentication Type=Passport;Server=https://devcrm.myco.com;Username=devuser@myco.com;Password=pwd" - this works both inside and outside the domain "myco.com"
2. Connection string format 2 (with Domain attribute): "Authentication Type=Passport;Server=https://devcrm.myco.com;**Domain**=myco;Username=devuser@myco.com;Password=pwd" - this only works inside the domain myco.com but NOT outside (exception: The authentication endpoint Kerberos was not found on the configured Secure Token Service!)
   ﻿

The key is in the **Xrm.Client.CrmConnection.ClientCredential**:

If Domain is NOT specified in the connection string, when connecting from **outside** domain, Xrm.Client.CrmConnection.ClientCredentials.UserName is populated whereas the ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredentials.UserName is empty.

But if the Domain is specified, Xrm.Client.CrmConnection.ClientCredentials.UserName becomes null and Xrm.Client.CrmConnection.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredentials.UserName populated, which led to the service trying to authenticate user as a Windows AD user so of course it would fail when running app from outside Windows domain. And it explains why the same app works inside the domain even with Domain specified in the connection string.

For more detail, refer here for my original post asking for help in [Dynamics CRM Forum](https://community.dynamics.com/crm/f/microsoft-dynamics-crm-forum/392407/organizationservice-connect-error-the-authentication-endpoint-kerberos-was-not-found-on-the-configured-secure-token-service-from-developer-viewpoint/1059105#1059105)